# How to set proxy server for Json Web Keys

Tags: json, jwt, jose4j, jwk

I'm trying to build JWKS object for google JSON web keys to verify the signature of JWT token received from google. Inside our corporate environment, we need to set the proxy server to reach out external one. Below code runs outside the corporate environment.

`HttpsJwks https_jwks = new HttpsJwks(GOOGLE_SIGN_KEYS);
List<JsonWebKey> jwks_list = https_jwks.getJsonWebKeys();`

Library: jose4j0.4.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpsJwks](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.1/org/jose4j/jwk/HttpsJwks.html) uses the [SimpleGet](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.1/org/jose4j/http/SimpleGet.html) interface to make the HTTP call. By default it's an instance of [Get](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.1/org/jose4j/http/Get.html), which uses java's HttpsURLConnection. So I think using the https proxy properties should work - see   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html for more about `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`.

If you need to do something more exotic for whatever reason, you can [set your own implementation/instance of SimpleGet on the HttpsJwks instance](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.1/org/jose4j/jwk/HttpsJwks.html#setSimpleHttpGet(org.jose4j.http.SimpleGet)) too.

Comment: it worked for me by setting https proxy properties. thanks.

Comment: In the next version the proxy can be set pragmatically too  https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/commits/48f5faf5230006dd874d530a75920316ded8d800